# Search in Master/detail flow

Tags: android, search, master-slave

I'm trying to implement a search in the link Mastеr / detail flow. but the search itself does not occur. I looked through many examples and did not find a solution. Please help. The error occurs in the 35 filter line

> An exception occured during performFiltering()!
>   java.lang.NullPointerException at
>   com.forma.zsuforma.content_field.CustomFilter.performFiltering(CustomFilter.java:35)

There is a body filter mistake in line 35: NullPointerException. I don't know to do.

```
public class CustomFilter extends Filter{
            public FormaListActivityBeret.MyAdapter adapter;
            public ArrayList<DummyContentBeret.DummyItemBeret> filterList;
            public CustomFilter(ArrayList<DummyContentBeret.DummyItemBeret> filterList,
    FormaListActivityBeret.MyAdapter adapter)
            {
                this.adapter=adapter;
                this.filterList=filterList;

            }
```

This line is giving me trouble:

```
           for (int i=0;i<filterList.size();i++)

                    {
                     ...
                    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: please, still point to my example)). I've been through many options .... (((

Comment: Which line? There are no line numbers for your provided code

Comment: **line 35*** for (int i=0;i<filterList.size();i++)

Comment: If you're getting a nullpointerexception you're probably passing a null `ArrayList<DummyContentBeret.DummyItemBeret>` to your `CustomFilter` class. Find out why you're sending a null `ArrayList`

Comment: and how to find out? file data- public static final List<DummyItemBeret> ITEMS = new ArrayList<>();
     public static final Map<String, DummyItemBeret> ITEM_MAP = new HashMap<>(); standarrt Android Studio

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to say. Have you tried using the debugger?

Comment: Yes, there is no critical error, but the filter does not work and this error in the log

Comment: Need a listing of the main file?

Comment: Just because the program doesn't crash does not mean there is no critical error. If you're sending a null list then I'd consider that pretty critical unless sending null is intended. Just include the relevant code.

Comment: Here's what, I'm in stupor, I do not know what .. (((